# How to use multiple fork() running at the same time? and how to use semaphore in c?

Tags: c, concurrency, multiprocessing, semaphore, dining-philosopher

I'm working on assignment where the professor is asking for a solution to solve the dinning philosopher problem using semaphores.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAX_THINKING_TIME 1500  /* maximum thinking time in milliseconds */
#define MIN_THINKING_TIME 1000  /* minimum thinking time in milliseconds */
#define MAX_EATING_TIME   1000  /* maximum eating time in milliseconds */
#define MIN_EATING_TIME   750   /* minimum eating time in milliseconds */

/*
 * Macros to encapsulate the POSIX semaphore functions.
 */
#define semaphore_create(s,v)   sem_init( &s, 0, v )
#define semaphore_wait(s)           sem_wait( &s )
#define semaphore_signal(s)         sem_post( &s )
#define semaphore_release(s)    sem_destroy( &s )
typedef sem_t semaphore;

// Each chopstick is represented by a semaphore (shared between all processes).
semaphore *chopstick;

int NUM_PHILOSOPHERS; /* number of philosophers */
int NUM_REPETITIONS;  /* number of cycles */

/*
 * Generating a random number within a range.
 */
unsigned int randr(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
    double scaled = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
    return (max - min +1) * scaled + min;
}

/*
 * To pick up his chopsticks, a philosopher does a semaphore wait on each.
 * Alternating order prevents deadlock.
 */
void pickup_chopsticks(int index)
{
    if(index % 2 == 0) /* Even number: Left, then right */
    {
        semaphore_wait(chopstick[(index+1) % NUM_PHILOSOPHERS]);
        printf("Philosopher #%d: I am picking up the left chopstick!\n", index+1);
        semaphore_wait(chopstick[index]);
        printf("Philosopher #%d: I am picking up the right chopstick!\n", index+1);
    }
    else /* Odd number: Right, then left */
    {
        semaphore_wait(chopstick[index]);
        printf("Philosopher #%d: I am picking up the right chopstick!\n", index+1);
        semaphore_wait(chopstick[(index+1) % NUM_PHILOSOPHERS]);
        printf("Philosopher #%d: I am picking up the left chopstick!\n", index+1);
    }
}

/*
 * To drop his chopsticks, a philosopher does a semaphore signal on each.
 * Order does not matter.
 */
void drop_chopsticks(int index)
{
    printf("Philosopher #%d: I am dropping the right chopstick!\n", index+1);
    semaphore_signal(chopstick[index]);
    printf("Philosopher #%d: I am dropping the left chopstick!\n", index+1);
    semaphore_signal(chopstick[(index+1) % NUM_PHILOSOPHERS]);
}

/*
 * Simulate a philosopher - endlessly cycling between eating and thinking
 * until his "life" is over.
 */
void start_philosopher(int index)
{
    int i; // A counter.

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_REPETITIONS; i++)
    {
        /* Hungry */
        printf("Philosopher #%d (Cycle #%d): I am hungry!\n", index+1, i+1);
        pickup_chopsticks(index);

        /* Eating */
        printf("Philosopher #%d (Cycle #%d): I am eating!\n", index+1, i+1);
        usleep(1000 * randr(MIN_EATING_TIME, MAX_EATING_TIME));
        drop_chopsticks(index);

        /* Thinking */
        printf("Philosopher #%d (Cycle #%d): I am thinking!\n", index+1, i+1);
        usleep(1000 * randr(MIN_THINKING_TIME, MAX_THINKING_TIME));
    }

    printf("Philosopher #%d: I am dead!\n", index+1);
    exit(0);
}

/*
 * The main function.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // If the input arguments are not 2 elements, display a message and return.
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("You have to insert arguments in the form:\n");
        printf("Number_of_Philosopher Number_of_repeats\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set value of NUM_PHILOSOPHERS and NUM_REPETITIONS from the user input.
    NUM_PHILOSOPHERS = atoi(argv[1]);
    NUM_REPETITIONS  = atoi(argv[2]);
    int i; // A counter.

    // Allocate memory for the semaphores.
    chopstick = malloc(NUM_PHILOSOPHERS * sizeof(semaphore));

    // Create semaphores to represent "one user at a time" chopsticks.
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
        semaphore_create(chopstick[i], 1);

    // Create n processes for n philosophers
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        if(fork() == 0) start_philosopher(i);
        else wait();
    }
    // Release semaphore resources.
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
        semaphore_release(chopstick[i]);

    // Free the memory.
    free(chopstick);

    return 0;
}
```

and when I run it, I got the following:

```
$ ./run 2 2
Philosopher #1 (Cycle #1): I am hungry!
Philosopher #1: I am picking up the left chopstick!
Philosopher #1: I am picking up the right chopstick!
Philosopher #1 (Cycle #1): I am eating!
Philosopher #1: I am dropping the right chopstick!
Philosopher #1: I am dropping the left chopstick!
Philosopher #1 (Cycle #1): I am thinking!
Philosopher #1 (Cycle #2): I am hungry!
Philosopher #1: I am picking up the left chopstick!
Philosopher #1: I am picking up the right chopstick!
Philosopher #1 (Cycle #2): I am eating!
Philosopher #1: I am dropping the right chopstick!
Philosopher #1: I am dropping the left chopstick!
Philosopher #1 (Cycle #2): I am thinking!
Philosopher #1: I am dead!
Philosopher #2 (Cycle #1): I am hungry!
^Z
[6]+  Stopped                 ./run 2 2
```

As you can see, I have two problems:

- Process n+1 is not executing unless process n is done.
- In previous test of running the program, it's being stuck at when the second philosopher is requesting for picking up the chopsticks. It seems that the semaphore is not signaled and the philosopher is waiting for a signal.

Can you please help me to fix the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem (1) is solved by moving the wait() outside the loop performing the fork.

Problem (2) is solved by allocating the memory using mmap() with the MAP_SHARED flag to allow it to be shared amongst the children, and using the sem_init(&s, 1, v) option for the sem_init call - using the 0 as the second option means that it is for intra-process (i.e. in the same pid, without being a child using fork).

```
chopstick = mmap(0, NUM_PHILOSOPHERS * sizeof(semaphore), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Comment: Should I include some headers to use `PROT_READ`, `PROT_WRITE`, `MAP_SHARED`, and `MAP_ANONYMOUS`?

Comment: nice, this works great. But when the program finishes, it prints `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: Well, I just remove `free(chopstick);` and it solves the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't add that you need to use munmap(chopstick, NUM_PHILOSOPHERS * sizeof(semaphore)) to free the memory correctly!

Comment: But now the arguments don't match!

Comment: You need to issue the wait() call as many times as there are philosophers. Wait only operates on the result of one fork(). What do you mean by 'the arguments don't match?'

Comment: Additionally, the wait needs to be before the loop issuing the semaphore_release - that destroys the semaphores, making them invalid for use in the children!!

Comment: I mean `mmap` has more parameters than `munmap`

Comment: munmap only takes two parameters - the address from which to start unmapping and the size of the item to be unmapped - those are the only things it needs to unmap. The remainder of the parameters for mmap were needed to construct the mapping

Answer (score 1):

In the loop where you fork new processes, the new parent process (where `fork` returns non-zero) you wait for the new process to finish. Drop the `else` and call `wait` outside the loop.

Comment: Should I call `wait()` more than one time?

Comment: Yes, you need to call `wait()` in a loop at the very bottom (before `free(chopstick)`, `NUM_PHILOSOPHERS` times.  Each `wait` cleans up after one child.